# java XML parsing using jaxb or dom?

Tags: java

I have a following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Abc version="3" xmlns="urn:Abc-v3">
  <Ele1>      
    <SubElement name ="name" description="DO">
      <Node version="C" siteURL="https://example.com" />
      <Client>
        <ClientId>1</ClientId>
        <ClientSecret>Yes</ClientSecret>
      </Client>   
    </SubElement>    
    <SubElement name ="SharePointOLDev1" description="DEV1">
      <Node version="C" siteURL="https://example.com" />    
      <Local>
        <LocalId>id</LocalId>
        <Password>password</Password>
      </Local>
    </SubElement>
    <SubElement name="AS" description="wow">
      <DB connection="connection" />
    </SubElement>
  </Ele1>
  <Ele2>
    <Content ID="A" co="LD">
      <Description>Simple Docs</Description>
      <Serve    
        Lib1="TEST"
        Lib2="yes"
        Lib3="yes"
        Lib4="no"
        Lib5="no"
        Lib6="name">
        <Hole enabled="false" count="200"  />

        <Fol enabled="false" count="100"  />

        <Role enabled="No" validate="false" />
        <FetchFilenameAttribute connection="SAP-AS" delay="3" />
      </Serve>
     </Content>
  <Content ID="B" co="OL">
      <Description>Simple Docs </Description>
      <Serve    
        Lib1="TEST"
        Lib2="yes"
        Lib3="yes"
        Lib4="no"
        Lib5="no"
        Lib6="name"">
        <Hole enabled="false" count="200"  />

        <Fol enabled="false" count="100"  />

        <Role enabled="No" validate="false" />
      </Serve>
     </Content>
  </Ele2>
  <Ele3>
    <CNode attr="hai" attr1="bye" />
  </Ele3>

</Abc>
```

I need to parse this XML file and assign values to its corresponding class objects.Which is the best option to parse such an xml file.
JAXB sounds good to me but the POJOs were already written by someone and now i will have to rewrite and deploy them.ALso teh xml file has some errors while running xjc command.
DOM approach seems to be very cumbersome n error prone.
Please suggest.
PS:Kindly excuse my beginner level knowledge.

Comment: It depends. StAX can also be a good idea. If you use Jaxb, you might have to write some glue code to convert it to POJO, but that glue code is usually short. It's hard to tell without seeing the POJOs.

Answer (score 0):

the JDK project comes with SAX(Simple API for XML) accessible by importing `org.xml.sax.*`.
You may take a look at this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_sax_parse_document.htm for an introduction to the subject.